# Continuous phase transitions in statistical models with binary degrees of freedom

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

Except from the Ising, is there any other statistical mechanics model that exhibits second order phase transition in two dimensions that has binary degrees of freedom?

Comment: Are you insisting on binary degrees of freedom? If yes, one example is the [Ashkin-Teller model](https://physics.anu.edu.au/theophys/baxter_book.php), which can be seen as two interacting Ising models (so, you really have two spins per site, or two interacting planar layers, each containing Ising spins). Since the two "planes" can order at different temperatures, this model undergoes (in part of its phase diagram) two temperature-driven phase transitions.

Comment: There are many variants, but I don't know which give rise to critical points (for instance any Potts model with $2^n$ states can be realized as coupled Ising models but, for any $n\geq 3$, the phase transition becomes 1st order, while the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ reduce to the Ising model and a particular case of the Ashkin-Teller model respectively...).

Answer (score 1):

There are several models (Potts, Ashkin-Teller, ...) undergoing a second-order phase transition in 2D but with a number of states per spin larger than 2. Allowing only two states per spin, your model is basically equivalent to the Ising model. When trying to write an Hamiltonian, any term involving only one spin that you can write would be equivalent to the coupling with a magnetic field (or a constant). In the same way, the only possible way to couple two Ising spins is the exchange interaction of the Ising model.

Comment: I dont quite agree. You can introduce for example competitive interactions in next next neighbor spin. In this case the thermodynamics of the system is not equivalent with the classical Ising. however i dont now if this kind of models exhibits phase transitions of second order.

Comment: Oh, I see. I would still call it an Ising model. You are referring to the so-called ANNNI model. As far as I remember, this model undergoes two Kosterlitz-Thouless transitions but there may be a regime with only one continuous transition (see W. Selke (1988), 
 Phys. Rep. 170, 213).

Comment: As I mention in my comments above, the Ashkin-Teller model can be seen as a model with Ising spins, but with another graph (two copies of the square lattice) and an additional 4-body coupling. In this sense, it is a 2d model with binary degrees of freedom undergoing a continuous (actually up to two) phase transition as the temperature is varied. One can then construct may variant of the Ising model by adding additional many-body interactions. But I don't know which of these variants give rise to a continuous phase transition.

Comment: You are right, Yvan. Even on the square lattice, an Ising model with next to next-nearest neighbors can be in the same universality class as the Ashkin-Teller model (varying critical exponents), see S. Jin, A. Sen, and A. W. Sandvik, Ashkin-Teller Criticality and Pseudo-First-Order Behavior in a Frustrated Ising Model on the Square Lattice, Phys. Rev. Lett. 108, 045702 (2012).